# How to search for a value and its index in multiple lists, that have been imported from a CSV file without any built in functions?

Tags: python, list, search

I have imported a CSV file that has a total of 10 lists. How can I search for a value (string in this case) and have the value printed along with its index to be printed?

```
import csv

values = []
for line in open("my_list.csv", "r"):
    delimiter = ','
    list = line.split(delimiter)
    for value in line:
        (values.append(value))
    print(list)
```

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module? Why can't you use any built-in functions? Even if you're not using any built-ins, it's not good practice to mask them. And you're not doing anything with that reference anyway. And I'm not sure what you mean by a value's index - would that be its column?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Do you know how to do it with built-ins?  By value's index, i mean which index of the list will it be located in. Pardon me for my language, i am new to programming.

Comment: I suggest you look up a tutorial on how to use the included `csv` module. I don't know why you want to include each item's index in the resulting `list`; it seems redundant. It's probably an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).